# error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories" in typeorm

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

What is wrong with this query?

```
            await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(ImageEntity)
                                     .createQueryBuilder('image')
                                     .leftJoin('image.entries', 'entries')
                                     .leftJoin('entries.categories', 'categories')
                                     .leftJoin('categories.parentCategory', 'parentCategories')
                                     .where('categories.id = :categoryId OR parentCategories.id = :categoryId', {userId, categoryId})
                                     .delete()
                                     .execute();
```

It throws the `missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"` error. Putting `from(ImageEntity)` after `.delete()` does not work.

Here is the whole trace back from the debugger:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: START TRANSACTION
query: DELETE FROM "image" WHERE categories.id = $1 OR parentCategories.id = $2 -- PARAMETERS: [4,4]
query failed: DELETE FROM "image" WHERE categories.id = $1 OR parentCategories.id = $2 -- PARAMETERS: [4,4]
error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/albert/Documents/projects/fxj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:581:48)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/albert/Documents/projects/fxj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:380:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/albert/Documents/projects/fxj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:116:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 121,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '27',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '3301',
  routine: 'errorMissingRTE'
}
query: ROLLBACK
query: ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I hope the issue in the `where` part, you've not put it in quotes -> `.where('categories.id = :categoryId OR parentCategories.id = :categoryId', {userId, categoryId})`

Comment: @ArtOlshansky Oh, my bad, I didn't copy it correctly from the code, in the code I used a string variable and here I decided to put in a string but did not copy the quotes(

Comment: @ArtOlshansky I've just posted some additional debug info on the error. Would you please have a look?